# Updating a MySQL database via PDO and tokens - all parameters being set to last value in dataset

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

As the title states: I am trying to update specific records in a MySQL data base using PDO and tokens to secure against any injection.

Here is my code:

Some arrays to help build the query:

```
$id = 1234
$values = array ('a','b','c',);
$variables = array ($A, $B, $C);
```

The query built via loop:

```
$sql =  "UPDATE table1 SET ";   
        foreach($values as $value)
        {
        $sql .="$value = :$value, ";
        }
        $sql = rtrim($sql,', ');    
        $sql .=" WHERE id = '$id'";
```

Execution of query via PDO:

```
try     
{
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=db01', $username, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
foreach(array_combine($values, $variables) as $value=>$variable)
{
$stmt->bindParam(":$value", $variable);
}

$stmt->execute();
```

The result:
Every field in the specified record (matching $id) is set to the same value, which is always equal to the contents of the last variable listed in the array (in this example they would all contain the value held in $C)

echoing the SQL query shows it has been constructed correctly.

Any ideas? Thanks for your consideration

Comment: `$variable` in your `foreach` is a _value_, not a _reference_. You may consider using `$stmt->bindParam(":$value",$arr[$value]);` to bind (pre-saving `array_combine(...)` to `$arr`).

Comment: Hey @Passerby, this was exactly the issue, thanks. If you'd like to write it up as a solution I will give you the rep you deserve :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending from comment:

In your `foreach` loop, the `$variable` is a *value*, not a *reference*, so when you `mysqli_stmt::execute()`, you actually end up using the last `$variable`.

To avoid that, you'll have to use something like this:

```php
$cache=array_combine($values,$variables);
foreach($cache as $value=>$variable)
{
  $stmt->bindParam(":$value",$cache[$value]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make this way:

```
  foreach(array_combine($values, $variables) as $value=>$variable)
  {
    $stmt->bindParam(":$value", $variable);
    $stmt->execute();
   }
```

Execute your query inside the for loop. Don't execute your query once the loop is done because it will only get the last value of your array. It will only execute once.

Comment: Ah that makes sense - thank you, however the statement now returns the error: 
**Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens**

I performed a `count` on the two arrays to confirm that they contained the same number of elements.